# Yarn failing to start service based on "path/" argument must be of type string, Vue application, windows10

Tags: windows, yarnpkg

I am using a template, Vue cli3 application and it stopped working and I don't recall why. The error I am receiving is when I try to start the application I get this error.

```
yarn run serve
yarn run v1.16.0
error An unexpected error occurred: "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received type object".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\node\\TradeTriggers\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I can delete the `node_modules` and `package.json.lock`

I cannot do anything with yarn. No yarn install, yarn run serve, nothing and npm doesn't seem to want to run the application. I'm sorry there are a lot of tools to know in the JS world!

The machine is a windows10 machine and I cannot find yarn in my env variables, so the issue may lie there. I even tried installing the Yarn MSI but my version is still the one I installed through npm a while ago, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem that was caused by yarn looking at first the global settings file, ie global registry. It might be similar. On Windows, first check your yarn config path:

yarn config bin

Windows shows the path. Then in that folder, check whether you have a "rc" file, ie that is yarn configuration.
Try move this file out of the folder, for test. Have it as a copy somewhere else, where you can restore it if this does not help.
Then, once file is out, run your yarn commands again like you used to.

Sideline: on Linux, I had to remove a leftover buggy .yarnrc file in
/usr/local/share/.yarnrc
to get similar things working again. It was not a Vue app, but similar kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you are using Yarn Workspaces and have incompatible directories in the `packages/` directory.

In my scenario, I used git subtrees to pull another repo into my project's `packages/` directory. This directory had a `package.json` file, but it did not have compatible values for the fields required by Yarn Workspaces.

Moving the problematic package out of `packages/` should fix this issue.